# how to get the x to the pow y in C under c99 standard

Tags: c, gcc, c99

I have `#include<math.h>`,
and I tried to use pow(x, y) and powf(x, y).
but it seems neither of them are under c99 standard.
and I use the command `gcc -std=c99 test.c -o test` to compile.
what function there exists I can use?

Comment: If your program is named `test`, be sure to run it as `./test` and not simply `test`... :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For *histerical* reasons, the math library is not bundled in with the rest of the Standard Library. You have to manually add it to the compilation with the `-lm` option to gcc.

```
gcc -std=c99 test.c -o test -lm
```

Comment: @R..: I've always wanted to say that ... in a meaningful sentence!

Answer (score 6):

Did you link with the math lib?

```
  gcc -std=c99 test.c -o test -lm
```